# Typing support for ol v5.1.3 needed

Tags: typescript, html-lists, openlayers, openlayers-5

When will there be typing support for ol? I am using this inside an angular app and could really use an @types/ol. The current @types/ol out there just imports from @types/openlayers and the types dont quite match up from v4 to v5.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently being worked on.

See this PR: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/8345